# Why do my credits reset to zero when I leave a planet?

Tags: endless-sky

I am pretty far into Endless Sky. Suddenly, the number of credits began resetting to zero every time I leave a planet and I have no idea why.
Why do my credits reset to zero upon leaving a planet?